# Help with drawing the phase plane of a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $\frac{dx}{dt} = 3-y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = x-3$

I need to draw the phase diagram of the system; list all the equilibrium points; determine the stability of the equilibrium points; and describe the outcome of the system from various initial points.

I have started off by determining the x and y isoclines:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = 3-y=0\implies y=3$

$\frac{dx}{dt} > 0$ if $y < 3$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} < 0$ if $y > 3$

**Sign of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ :**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PELS.jpg)

$\frac{dy}{dt} = x - 3 = 0 \implies x=3$

$\frac{dy}{dt} > 0$ if $x>3$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} < 0$ if $x < 3$

**Sign of $\frac{dy}{dt}$**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wjbp.jpg)

**Equlibrium points**

One equlibrium point at $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$ which is the point where $x = 3$ and $y = 3$

Am I on the right track here?  I am struggling to use these calculations to draw the phase diagram.  Please could someone give me a tip to at least start the phase plane.

Please see example of what the textbook requires:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1eCn.jpg)

Comment: Is this for a class? Does your teacher/textbook expect you to draw the phase plane just by getting a few points and completing the picture by connecting the dots? Or do they expect you to numerically draw it? Or by solving the system?

Comment: For a class yes.  Please have a look at the textbook example that I attached.

Comment: You are on the right track. Just like in the photo of the book you uploaded, draw a graph and draw your isoclines which will have your equilibrium point.

Then in the four quadrants created by your isoclines determine whether $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ are positive or negative. Lines in the quadrants must all have slopes as you just found. For example, in the top left quadrant $\dot x <0$ and $\dot y<0$, so all the vectors must point down and left. 

Once you do this for all four of the quadrants it should become apparent, just by following what the slopes must be, what the system is like.

Comment: I did solve it.  Thanks very much to @eli